# select statement returing one colum with multiple rows. I have to store those values into one variable for future use using sql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the values using the below code

```
$query="select document_id from certificate_documents where certificate_id=$certificate_id";

$res = db_query($query);
        $row_count = db_num_rows($res);


$doc_id=array();

    for($j=1;j<=$row_count;$j++){

    $document_copy = db_fetch_object($res);

    $doc_id[$j]=$document_copy->document_id;


print "$doc_id[$j]";

}
```

But the above code print nothing.
I have to use this value into another query . How can i get this? please help.

Comment: +-------------+
| document_id |
+-------------+
|        3877 |
|        3903 |
+-------------+ this is the output of above query . i need to store it to another variable and use this value to make an another query

Comment: __Edit__ your question instead pasting data in comments.

Comment: Does above query return more than 1 record or only 1 ?

Comment: @Ahmed , the query will give more than one record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$query="select document_id from certificate_documents where certificate_id=$certificate_id";

$res = db_query($query);        
$doc_id=array();    
while($document_copy = db_fetch_object($res)) {            
    $doc_id[]=$document_copy->document_id;        
}
print_r($doc_id);
```

Comment: Okay thanks. one more doubt how can i use this "$doc_id" to another query . for ex: $i=1;can i use this by "$doc_id[$i]"

Comment: Yes, you can also go through loop using `foreach`

Comment: one more doubt is how can i use this value into another query like below is my foreach loop    foreach($doc_id as $docs){
print "$docs";
}

Comment: Tell me what is your use (example) and then I can say how to use?

Comment: and my query is q1= "select * from documents where id =$docs"; or anything else.

Comment: Then you can use `id IN (implode(",",$doc_id)) ` instead of foreach

Comment: foreach($doc_id as $docs){
q1= "select * from documents where id =$docs";
}    Is this a right way?